# python - convert xml to numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, xml-parsing

I have an xml file that looks something like this:

```
<root>
  <data_coeffs>
    <coeffs_0>6.891826 -1.674641 -0.002788087 -1.662732E-06</coeffs_0>
    <coeffs_1>6.916866 -1.673133 -0.002835441 -3.022999E-06</coeffs_1>
    <coeffs_2>6.958995 -1.667976 -0.002869904 -7.788709E-06</coeffs_2>
  </data_coeffs>
</root>
```

I would like to create a numpy array with the coefficients (in this example a 3 by 4 array).

This is the code I have so far:

```
import xmltodict
import numpy as np

file_path = r'coeff.xml'
with open(file_path) as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

data = doc['root']['data_coeffs']
s = 'coeffs_'
C = np.zeros((3,4))
for i in range(3):
    C[i,:] = np.array(data[s+str(i)])
```

This does not work because the data cannot be converted to float from unicode.

How can I convert the data to float so it can go into the numpy array? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You need to `split` that `data` string into substrings representing single numbers.  e.g. `[float(i) for in '123 343 343'.split()]`.